# Make React-native-progress bar show progress

Tags: react-native, progress-bar

i am using this package for progress bar https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress on the splashscreen
Now i have this as my screenshot

[image: Screenshot-1672849213.png]

1.) I want the progress bar to have white background
2.) I want it not to be stationary, i want it to be showing signs of progress

My code is looking thus :

```
import {Image, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

const SplashScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => navigation.replace('HomePage'), 6000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={require('../assets/logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />
      <Progress.Bar style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}} progress={0.3} width={200} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SplashScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'#28282B',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 650,
    height: 650,
  },
});
```

Please what Do i appear not to be doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, all progress indicators have these two props:

| Prop | Description | Default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| color | Fill color of the indicator. | rgba(0, 122, 255, 1) |
| unfilledColor | Color of the remaining progress. | None |

[See the docs for more](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress#properties-for-all-progress-components)

In order for you to show progress, you have to have data about a process that's going on.  For example, if you have a download going on, you could pass a callback to the downloader that would set a local progress state as the download progressed.

Also, take a look at the source code for the progress bar - it's a very simple task that shouldn't really require a package.  You'll learn more from doing it yourself.

Comment: i saw that, but it did not specify how to use it, if it did , i wont be asking

Comment: you can add them as props to the progress bar and use any color RN will understand.  `<Progress.Bar color='red' unfilledColor='#123456' ... />

Comment: the color sets fine, the progressbar , no

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a package for this, you could easily make your own component.  Here's an example, you can change the styles to whatever suits your needs, or make them able to be passed in as props.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#CCC',
    borderColor: '#0AF',
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderRadius: 3,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  progress: {
    height: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#0AF',
  },
});

const ProgressBar = ({ progress }) => (
  <View style={styles.container>
    <View style={[styles.progress, { width: `${progress * 100}%`}] />
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Sorry couple of errors here, on the style part. Can you pls correct and show me how to use this component you created

Comment: Yes, I noted you could change the styles, I'll let you do that. What don't you understand about how to use the component?